# Old DHCP IP showing in ipconfig /all

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server

I recently migrated a 2003 DHCP database to a 2008 r2. The newly configured workstation will pick up the right IP settings including DNS, DHCP server, and gateway but the old workstations will still resolve to the old DHCP server's IP. I run these commands with admin privilege to my test workstation:

```
ipconfig /release 
net stop dhcp 
net start dhcp 
ipconfig /renew
```

but the result of the ipconfig /all still points to the old DHCP server IP. Also, I manually deleted one DHCP record for testing, I issue the same commands it picked up an IP but its still showing the old DHCP server IP and it's not showing on my current DHCP server address lease table. Any suggestions.

Also, I added the new dhcp server ip to my switch and router.

Comment: Did you remove the old ips?

Comment: I ran into this issue. Ended up having to re-image the machine.

Answer (score 0):

If the both the 2003 and 2008 servers are running, make sure the the DHCP server service is stopped on the 2003 server.  If the clients are on a different subnet than the server, the router for the client subnet should be configured only to forward the DHCP request to the new server.  Sometimes this is called BOOTP, which uses the same port as DHCP.

Comment: The 2003 server was demoted and decommissioned. The router is also configured to forward DHCP request to the new DHCP server but when renewing IP (from workstation) the DHCP server IP still points to the old server.